# Pthread query: Sequence of threads error

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int num_threads=3;

int state=0;

pthread_cond_t cond;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void* threadA(void* args) {

int i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++){ 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        while(state == 1 || state == 2) pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);

        printf("Thread A\n");
        state = (state+1)%num_threads;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
}

void* threadB(void* args) {

int i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++){ 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        while(state == 0 || state == 2)pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);

        printf("Thread B\n");
        state = (state+1)%num_threads;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
}

void* threadC(void* args) {

int i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++){ 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        while(state == 1 || state == 0) pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);

        printf("Thread C\n\n");
        state = (state+1)%num_threads;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
}


int main() {

pthread_t tid[3];

pthread_cond_init(&cond,NULL);
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);

pthread_create(&tid[0],NULL,threadA,NULL);
pthread_create(&tid[1],NULL,threadB,NULL);      
pthread_create(&tid[2],NULL,threadC,NULL);

return 0;
```

}

QUESTION: With the above code, I wish to print
          threaA threadB threadC sequentially 5 times.
          But the answer is undeterministic. While the order
          of threads is maintained, answers are not printed 5 times.
          Please help!!!

Comment: your `main` function ends before the threads are finished. You should `pthread_join` on them.

Comment: ... or leave `main()` by calling `pthread_exit()`.

Answer (score 3):

As @mch mentioned in the comment, you need to wait for the threads to finish before allowing the `main()` function to return:

```
pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
pthread_join(tid[2], NULL);
```

Now, after you add the joins above to the end of `main()`, your program will most often hang. This happens because the `pthread_cond_signal()` doesn't wake up all threads waiting on that condition variable. If the wrong thread is woke up (e.g. threadC signals the condition, but the thread that gets notified is not threadA), then all threads will be waiting on the condition and there will be nobody to signal that condition.

To fix this, you need to make sure all threads are woke up each time and let each thread decide on it's own if it is its turn or not (by that `while(state...) pthread_cond_wait(...);`). To do this, you can replace the calls to `pthread_cond_signal()` with calls to `pthread_cond_broadcast()`, which unblocks **all** threads currently blocked on that condition.

Comment: @Abhishek: Note that `pthread_cond_broadcast()` should be your default - `pthread_cond_signal()` is an optimisation (if your program is correct, then it will be still be correct if you replace every `pthread_cond_signal()` with `pthread_cond_broadcast()`).